# Is it possible to dynamically create a table visual in Power-Bi based on URL parameters?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'd like to have a table visual in Power-Bi which is dynamic in nature based on the URL parameters. Like for example, if in the URL I pass the values as "Country" and "State" , a table should be generated with only those two columns.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to dynamically filter visuals displayed columns in this way using the URL parameters, it is only for filtering the dataset.